# Neo4j and Spring - How to save autowired properties

Tags: java, spring, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

I cannot save autowired properties when using Spring components with Neo4j.

I have defined an abstract entity class which includes the graph id:

```
@NodeEntity
public abstract class DBEntity {
  @GraphId private Long id;
}
```

There is a data model with a parent and a child both defined as Spring components.
I have simplified the data model here, in reality it is a tree with several child nodes and levels:

```
@Component("DataModel")
@Scope("prototype")
public class DataModel extends DBEntity {
  @Autowired private DataStructure dataStructure;
  public TestDataStructure testDataStructure;
}

@Component("DataStructure")
@Scope("prototype")
public class DataStructure extends DBEntity {
  ...
}
```

For testing purposes, I have also defined a test data structure without Spring annotations:

```
public class TestDataStructure extends DBEntity {
  private String test;
  public TestDataStructure() {
    this.test = "test";
  }
}
```

Here is also the definition of my repository and the database service implementation:

```
@Repository
public interface DataModelRepository extends GraphRepository<DBEntity> {
  DBEntity save(DBEntity entity);
}

public class DatabaseServiceImpl implements DatabaseService {
  @Autowired private DataModelRepository modelRepository;
  public void putModel(DBEntity entity) {
   modelRepository.save(Entity);    
  }
}
```

Now, when I call putModel with an Spring-managed instance of DataModel, it will save the
DataModel instance and also an instance of TestDataStructure as nodes with 1:1 relationship. The instance of DataStructure and the relationship to the instance of DataModel will not be saved, although it is not null in the program.

How can I achieve to save the whole DataModel? Probably Spring interferes with the Neo4j mapping. I am not sure, why autowired properties might get lost in the cloning process or whatever Neo4j uses to get the data. Maybe someone can shed some light on this?

Comment: Perhaps, this describes the same issue: [link](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/neo4j/S1sYX613jmA)